# "For many years now" and "For some years now" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage

I want to know the meaning and the differences of these particular phrases:

1. for many years now / for many times now
2. for some years now / for some times now

can anyone also provide an implementation of these in sentences?

Comment: Have you looked any of these phrases up on the internet, or done any other research yourself to find the answers?

Answer (score 1):

For many years now - "many years" = a long time

for some years now - "some years" = a few years

Neither of the following are idiomatic: "for many times now" / "for some times now."

*For some **time** now* **is** idiomatic. "Some time" = an indefinite time. The general meaning of "It has been happening for some time now,." is "I am not sure how long it has been happening but it seems to have been happening for a long time."

Answer (score 0):

*Many X* means a large quantity of countable items.

*Some X* means a quantity that is not one or all, and typically implies not many.

> I have been at this job for many years.
>
> For some years now John has been my coworker.

Comment: i know the what some or many means. I want to know the meaning of that particular phrase and it's implementation like in this sentence
"For many years now we have been building systems and getting better at it"